# Need Help Deallocating Memory in a Class Destructor

Tags: c++

I receive the following error when I run my test program:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nmhfs.png]

The error goes away if I comment out "delete name," but I can't seem to figure out why. Hopefully someone can give me insight into a solution.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

class Shape
{
protected:
    string* name = new string;
public:
    Shape(string str)
    {
        *name = str; 
    }
    ~Shape()
    {
        delete name;  //Why does my program run if I comment this out?
        name = NULL;
    }

    virtual double getArea() const
        { return 0; }
    void setName(string str)
        { *name = str; }
    string getName() const
        { return *name; }
};

class Circle : public Shape
{
private:
    double radius;
public:
    Circle(string str = "", double r = 0) : Shape(str)
        { radius = r; }
    void setRadius(double r)
        { radius = r; }
    double getRadius() const
        { return radius; }
    virtual double getArea() const
        { return radius * radius * 3.14; }

    Circle operator= (const Circle &);
    Circle operator+ (const Circle &);
};

Circle Circle::operator= (const Circle &right)
{
    radius = right.radius;
    return *this;
}

Circle Circle::operator+ (const Circle &right)
{
    Circle tempCircle;
    tempCircle.radius = radius + right.radius;
    return tempCircle;
}

int main()
{
    Circle c1("c1",5);
    Circle c2("c2",10);
    Circle c3;

    c3 = c2 + c1;

    cout << "c1" << c1.getRadius() << endl;
    cout << "c2" << c2.getRadius() << endl;
    cout << "c3" << c3.getRadius() << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why are you doing this `string* name = new string;`?

Comment: And where is `counter` declared?

Comment: I'm just using a string pointer to test my understanding of correctly using a copy constructor with a pointer.

Comment: @Matimio your code does not contain any user-defined copy constructors, that's the whole problem

Answer (score 2):

You are using the compiler defined copy constructor when you use:

```
c3 = c2 + c1;
```

That is a problem when you have member data that are allocated from the heap and deallocated in the destructor.

Add proper copy constructors to your classes.

See [The Rule of Three](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three) for further details.

You can obviate the need for user defined copy constructors and copy assignment operators by changing

```
string* name = new string;
```

to

```
string name;
```

and changing the rest of your code accordinlgy.

Comment: Doesn't my overloaded operator functions fix that? Is there something wrong with my implementation of them?

Comment: @Matimio Where do you have an `operator=` for the `Shape` class that handles performing a deep copy of the `std::string*`? What you end up doing is getting 2 or more different class instances pointing the same `std::string*` which means things go bad after `delete` is performed by the first instance.

Comment: I'm just using this program to study for my upcoming test. I was just seeing if I could properly use a copy constructor with a pointer.

Comment: Your overload functions are only partially correct. They don't handle the base class part at all.

Comment: "Doesn't my overloaded operator functions fix that?" - Just try your class with `Shape(const Shape&) = delete;` and see what the compiler has to say about that ;-) Same with the assignment operator.

Comment: @RSahu I wasn't aware I had to create a copy constructor for my base Shape class if I was purely using Circle class.

Comment: @Matimio The base class needs to have it's state properly copied too.

Comment: Why doesn't making Shape an abstract base class fix this problem since I can't have an instance of Shape at that point?

Comment: @Matimio, that requires a long explanation that is not appropriate as a comment. It will be better ask to a different question, if you can create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @M.M, indeed. Thanks.

Comment: @VolkerK deleting `Shape` assignment operator does not break compilation, the code does not call that function anyway.  But it would be a good idea to implement that function of course, in case a later change to the code does try to assign a Shape

Comment: OK. The actual instance of calling broken copy constructor is in the return of `operator+`

Comment: @VolkerK that code deletes copy-constructor. I was talking about deleting assignment operator.

Comment: deleting the Circle assignment operator would break compilation as well. But yes, my point was Shape's copy ctor.